# Matlab symbolic function inversion and substitution

Tags: matlab

I am solving equations of motions with Lagrange multipliers and the goal is to uncouple (oust) them from equations.
 It all comes to two equations for which I define appropriate functions of state variables, and final Lagrange multiplier lambda (that I want to remove):

*(x2 stands for second derivative)*

**x2 = Function_x(..., lambda)**

**y2 = Function_y(..., lambda)**

What I want to do now is to inverse one of these function in terms of lambda, e.g let's invert first one:

**lambda_from_1st = Function_x^(-1) (..., x2) = NewFun(..., lambda)**

and substitute it for lambda within second equation:

```
y2 = subs(y2,lambda,lambda_from_1st)
```

So the question is *either* how to perfom the inversion in Matlab syntax so I can insert lambda from one equation to another, *or* how to do this some other way (if Matlab does not support such inversion). I checked the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/performing-symbolic-computations.html#brvfwnf), but examples there were only the simple ones.

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: TL;DR simple example:
If you have y = 2x + 3, I have to obtain inverted function x = y/2 - 3. How to do this with Matlab Symbolic Toolbox syntax?

Comment: Have you tried `solve`? Of course your system has to have analytic inverse (and it can be helpful to specify any `assumptions`) for this symbolic approach to work.

Comment: The phrase you used "analytic inverse" made me look up something like that in google and here it is: finverse. Thank you! :)

http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/finverse.html

Comment: `finverse` can work well too – it's basically a simplified `solve`.